# probability density function over a continous variable

Tags: probability

> The probability density function of evaporation $E\,\textrm{mm/day}$ on any day during a year in a watershed is given by
>   $$
> f(E)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1/5 & 0\leq E\leq 5\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   The probability that E lies in between $2$ and $4$ in the watershed is ____.

I know procedure to find out the answer which is $0.4$ (using continuous variable), but I don't understand core concept of it. I can't visualize the graph for $f(E)$.
can somebody help me to visualize what they have been asking, I don't want to understand mathematics as a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Illustration of pdf]

You can think of $ f(x)\times \delta x $ as being roughly the probability that the evaporation is within a small amount of $ x $, or in formulae

$ P(x-\tfrac{1}{2} \delta x \leq E \leq x + \tfrac{1}{2}\delta x) \bumpeq f(x) \times \delta x $

Comment: Sorry, the picture didn't seem to come across on first go.  I think now fixed..

Comment: Thank you so much.